# Generate the shortest regex to match these but not those

Tags: code-challenge, regular-expression, code-generation, test-battery

## Challenge

Given two lists of strings where each string is of length 50 and each list is also of length 50 generate the shortest regex you can that fully matches all the strings in the first list and does not match any of the strings in the second list.

## Scoring

Your score will be the average length of the regexes your program outputs when applied to this file: https://pastebin.com/MvwPbH1G

In this file the lists are separated by a single newline and the pairs of lists by two newlines. Apply your program to each pair twice with once with the first list as the strings to match and once with the second list as the strings to match.

## Rules

- We will use Javascript flavor regexes for simplicity.

Comment: When you say fully match, does that mean that the regex has to match the full string (assuming leading ^ and trailing $ for engines that require it)?

Comment: @Neil yes that is what I meant

Comment: Python has a number of APIs for pattern matching, `re.fullmatch`, `re.match` and `re.search`. Which API's behaviour do you want us to support?

Comment: It would be nice if the users that voted to close this question could explain what is unclear in their minds.  So the OP can address it.

Answer (score 3):

## Score: 212.84

```python
import re

def ngraphs(ss):
	n = [set() for _ in ss[0]]
	for s in ss:
		for i in range(1, len(s) + 1):
			for j in range(len(s) - i + 1):
				n[i - 1].add(s[j:j + i])
	return n

while True:
	y = [input() for _ in " " * 50]
	input()
	n = [input() for _ in " " * 50]
	input()
	input()
	yngraphs = sum([sorted(a - b) for a, b in zip(ngraphs(y), ngraphs(n))], [])
	regex = yngraphs.pop(0)
	while not all(re.search(regex, a) for a in y):
		regex += "|" + yngraphs.pop(0)
	print("^.*(" + regex + ").*$")
	print()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZjJru28gZ3H5lNcGBncv8oxbASZFFAD9X3fUoYTUBIlqqdEdRTy7g5v2eUgyCQ4wMHeYiO2a31rU36Sbf1vf/vbsNDtOH8cGIAWdz/W/kCUsJ@M/fZv4Hfrj3//8ReGz5@//ei248f//DGsPxj7y5/@@lfwu18P2N8fiJr/8XX49fVAa49//vkPP2a8/mS//fjXH3/@1dXfa4z/p8Y/iv@raPXPKr9b/zKIJ3/@6x9R2/5kfxn/bRSFw19/A7878Hkd648VgIcMM/6RHhcWbfivEQ4rvf6vMf5e/P3Lj//@JzHMf5T9Yy7/XzX/@YH/YzVES3YtP//CxErh9icSQ6z/3gf6w4/6VzffQH/@59Lx3/7wz2Vcf/vtr3/48Ze/T6DHr@jpPzv9I93ozz@Jgr/PZ93OH2iefx74jwyjoyE//6PBH36gf7zp12v4fyzT33v613//8fv/9XuxPP9Ph/QY1vPn7//HH//l56/yf1T/8fvf/vgv/@X3/yz/7W9/k7vyoCRVmy1M5WxaFW2Gn8bMao9Z16fTSBFs5tLoJd9KTH1rd8BnbL1DvoQjiozz3dVD8zis3BSlsYrTPJE8aNRpjqo71RM8yiVYksMZ2VpPqueuE9HKS7p7U3HXesuO6cUnlushec@vXRQjK10tBu1aDtuc3Tw1HAm1vgVdiPfdSKty6J/LXjydqGsQZl0Nz6VwBwKGN/TOSNVsvWKNAs3Z59WadTthC7Gn/cnzy4qNJHjMfN30trwToEx9787LFngl9@/aNdZ5LyrHOWCR2UHuxysPiRaW1oxkb/pSqoNsyXnW7mqq9snTprJ6bWaltcrajYamosRrvsGpilHaqqVO5OzbxIrxeXU/KbGmb@ddT2znYaMTt42uq3sXNxTvavzu26M9dtv55QTa4wo0zdkptfV2OSAcqoD4tTeE59UkpzLPqXGicarUuftmLGUf0Ee0KHN5uVnyXOx7ww9bSqIfz@Z8PROz8mxoK428k4srA6qzAhyO7Lpmyi5cypJeIi07zkRNSycokQWVPk@OWacMi5NBmtiTjAksNIslXaKoYU22mE8ZsX1qkXmjxZDrRe2zvS0@NkjryMZ6afwcfEMZS0n9jhC5KtQqJCFxhKo2WHJW925wIXLvKBs3k2oPUXn6AHXd@2j4hlmH2rRTbB395MWTp2bXdC3pdA6WYYd6nsHUkR39qV1wwbBU@GYclzGNb2iMQbVBLZj2iC1oNdtW/45vgYPitOk3Nq/rgdYjRvb4fRKXDNU4LWkPg0nWD@ZnG0ZlXUqZ3iijirYgeZKQJmBibC/96NyzyLNuSgPmN8pSmJb6qAU32p2e57Qiy14O87SDLMQADl9e5Evgd9lZQF0pcM3CkcprGs6NZUZVdNyaNSShvZ3sfKvzAk1@nvOlDO2j6tzL3ktzZG6cvdyNGUQFOZRZWq8d@3FS8PhNxxZ4WRQ5i3eSMm@9c5DV4gsC5MbPmdtxQrGhoGpHZ6GmSbQtpPN7kJzihZhqr35KQVfXyarJQeIx3XvDoMVDvmo9SkanLZ@@GZbeukG8Zn1hJq3Ze@hZ85ymEScKGRvTJfVmvLnjmlvZJTFPgtg3SNICmEXWyD7a1@o5LYsVxJWM/LCsJhbTo9/bmXrwzh2p8DK9Y4ZRAK1vL/XmCyar/eh9sZqdOnR2nKJ9Mh6xF3uazzCXGbrSIsxiFIDoG3J1gnWrfLTAD003tyhIXBulcbjVXvNHl5fl5ZkzX9eVu3sJWrsZ9HDZ4C6fb6El/IPuQdrUiuZwGsM68YJ0bXi391dIs7SUGuAoDZviN5TvjW35WtpKmBYeT7kDTdK6HzboueXcqLawcc5Tsx@g7FtCL6jUzyoTahkVkkn7HmUbZJ@dvommn5m0x/OkQdPEi1GfoGlisR9f13m6uVK7kq0w9Z0sdPhIbyZliybtk8bjIbMuetxBTsGmvLbtlHGizHKT955RwYQc0JZPk8Cm1SzJzXCfFrLjHpev2U4OJC4@8s8yZL22vrtQFEUUKyqM43zwQxgOiTY6@@sYT4qNNcc@iJM8fevAmvXtTLxMi1Pnq2YxPk/pt9dst@SxlItbjhseav9KWgKOsJ26r7RToZ3EpcWVvQ6/LsctoviJB8tqQyERn4Xk1EbTqy4NqP1pd1bYp4G5pA1azpeL7Q62qlDlfYq8jQ@HkZS17AupmpxLXsFgtJNsdXHp3e658G4ZFq5vnZfGoWWT8zpdib/jMvOgrYa9CLYNnAS5fIlXZQ6HrFCfXNHMobzCu1@wN@jNjFVWBpHmcK8pvFSZHmA4kd5rleqOrZKsXBIaFRcrx6U6WbvjouDQ57af2M0pXh9LbyYAx6YKywAWxeEn0WevQx3d3DnfudBcxal9h0@6pBSWKudIx57bgrXN315Ze3XPRiKnw6WKW2/fSew01SrvUn80wQO1J2JyNeZm8qWg82Gh95PDKmRsh6Rgehr3c7ZdcC4miYcvNYLBDPx52yNp1Gg9AGld06Yp1irUaFuZ5q4vNQyda5HUxSDjbtPYSbKOeQu/d@Py5R202nl8ShtIY1gOL3@Y1SnXa/ZzEioVnHU@IWa2EcfCdGLJJEkHQvkaxiUlDlL5nCSy9cTGOLGqSE1St7Hdj6uS92gP1Hvjo1bTHkBt89vEZ/pX61DM3bxGcsTXDn3TwnjV4zBH5jm5hcwm8/jUcQcsDdxGjFx6Pyciw1OOzdM7n7I8w3FthqyuOac9i/Z8YsNWa3wHY9TFUTf1pk89uxp4xVzN6GXfkMIxEP@UL@y8Kx76xHMebK/yA@TT0OjhoNfY6jvN1WbV1Ha7jN1bv6yNWDmSqZk3xxz8vlQgfj4w0GrDfWVFK3ehk290mbIhW0Y9L@fxWgnJgouuyI8sHkYeE9oG8nooxsN@KrccKls72C7nWRtWyw3bC8ZelM1vGShKJjmP7Xe624CxWDQqnZJLVxlnF0lh3PiVH8iHoXVDjKKhR5LSh1yfz21Io8oCoIFxFBVCg3o3n6bQHINOLRTcCV8@0zmiRVQvZlnCTNwXWnRdMYAqCaW@Xdd37AOl3CmyGXUkV86c@LJTe33oa9FblJ8DqsplYyvQzMM11EdOMm97UvsefWHaX40NK@oap9djqMPK7ikez8IY2szsQWHOk2F5xpE/eotXWB59fOIkbM54mfGLL4OsUTiWlxHfYywY5gJ1M73F1VydvUW5FWgw0z9VUx1pr6/Tc3ryFb4RBpMln3OjTIk2gSxR13ILctkL6FnTTBNa3g1ddWbHdY@lo27QKHWtm9JsQqmmMUds/8RvhwVWus8oWM5CH2QWh7wNZaSwYR6TpfxOGD51thdzXNwjeEYe4Vf7xuJtQ2cxDeg/V0gYL2DW59KRz9JN3E7uNdpFwqSqGJzal75WKI3XhAP51GW6tiO3Ws@wZHWYOF@aZgqLQ70EWbR3k23AZfJSIVqmXliOHuRxKoS3nRr6jeW8KO@xOTSVreqLotiWZMvqgPPJBbPgztD0jaExX6GnuZe/ayspz3Xsp6IdujFS1RO1cS5NfgNSiFDmljr@3BgrKNBLvQpzMvabHvHueeUsiWqh9dKwmjX5Pr0Bwa2FA5LCrveTy/tgY3H@XuUXZF4xvFr/ScRv7Li@0ZldbebtMegqrKqNrfuNEJiKlJO2KP5LkUZs@iFjXRK71KJ8Pd5uc99iXkOgYsdV3qJMTXFhZdoPnsVTZZDuEM42X/ejLDzHfTyuSiYNoAgOAG5fI6cNtD/JFagbk@zdyIhTuDibXDreyRz0lXn3RvLqhu1sOaBZksf1urmQs5KMxzVNXHVfcmmuPywwLFieuQ/SBmXLv@y41UQFRL4@9U2WnM5LUo1HpXaHZks0x62khoGSv2XNgg7G9dAPWy8rKyC7jdxNy6MEQ6mtFcsRer0zOPez6aQYy5F2BOar5oXETJIpcwa@2XD9kVJLxmZrp9mxJ4nWd5aRuGcqXeaSH/Zb27sg1k2z6qCVgcG/RN9J4L@CcgJ7T3Gvjn0YBB@3/EiPR3V0EF9oY3RIaFkfWWDZ58VLctWrjKYqskitkjeETCEWIqZuu35/5tkt7ZRpm6plVgFBXceseBYxg0QdlX295unwX9WuLsy8@Zcb5I9v4NnuZa@YqKXHgFVHL0N6GcgjH371N9rbJClgeO59@JFVcaE1k8l3drN0rr7vFsANqFxuLNelb3cBo9@WvMJWXP1DWNY7I4BzvHrJpPvfYhl0rCPwaHOoBdl6fa7FZ1tKvV3nF7J1J6yJ2uxoVUkVpJW3C0yq5uP0wOLZr0@DnUbN4XaRDYvQI77g91HbIrmps6PwNwd7d33J2kyCwQEskIammacvULdB4RYdZYO/yJJmtyvDJ76P7D3dUh4FZpGapp0DHChySmndpvxoJxsMMvF@GVwvmZ1wIqksF5N@D3CJpzWpvFD4MHDjPny@7UQzZc9weepXW8M4tMY5Tlg39Trsm3H1XTbD0elviQTgDaRGGo5wDR2BX91RC5jTOzqVs9Tazqx62KrvSUmMPV/VIZhFtLAlnpzPVbXeUZhQt05SQa@8zvc@1ufImsVStUgwyeLQPjtfpqvg06yMqQlzyzjYlzyX6tNcR0UNOztSkOP2Xc1y7rnojLzXjMMXiZwQLma6cqt2PHcxsamI1pXzPIWzhSI3rtaoX6ypvCPVp0yNNA1YPeT4abVU/7y29JNEwJEfpazGfFmlrini6GyPW17aphTYve0QWHazbdxbjIyYsS91XdCzOwnCTLIqjcZa0V5zk28@C8UYar3zLzAL7elZKBCZnolcQevKWnTuZk/LdWKtsaW6PlXKltpt4fgfcTKQacO1YjVmpf0SntXHWKT0SI9uoXY6rKjbruyIj2rexfxddbtK4IhyUuQlhoN8@wvLW7Mqkouo0X0hF/nHnjZdH7ACS85ipdocASM4suHwSz2/A70W1NHAEDf9HtJeClKJq33pflFt3jHsu3jueALUYKZ6Wa/1FM@pABCkLqZcZV/4vK7tNaHtXsOVeS0N0bYpx0Aq0Aynr249WgtXMG6F14OZsymbdx0Y03XsTYeUkCeTanRP@uZSZwPr@7yrRe3KWSi55/vOj8lRZsvEm@8iWaFftRsxViwc8kK11HzANdngvd6XGPZtVpU81t2Q9NT0ZeWF9T62VFfi5tvE8Vj0DMdvD4jF9Hpzr8j4mACCTBjEkmTZKXKjb1BcUDWsdzUcjm5kBbt0ewNDH12qEebhgSm7kkr4XzhOUb1N@zA@kdM8CsknqMvbPIxa4bk5qJ6MQcm3ol2vgi@riopG3jH22inmpPVzJihMyIHa9NeuLGGjMAARubcTyjOSYrNOP9ZArmnZ4dwyCuLhdZbXQMswUy77paSZ0AEhkqY7T1FP97psj0F0G1mLVk/knvHSuOluZhEsRArTqZLm0pCDy7pKKiLYMyRX4ikhqoi7Jn1fWIN2dqH9fXFajqe@rApu9srYZQBAON1hW@7Z7D2srqpcwKJlyrojL2oSN5N9THe0taLnPI7ZXVhYBxrZqaMrSWBuh5@VAla8zLxuO4jtmn1xDJvETu4RMu7gKpY2Qdfc3Jw3NC40NWujhGrwiRCcrcU9OERkIc2Q5ZAQereTE3xO6@YVOPe5txWzMjfFi@CJ6Vb0TzM3NElj24gbU4CmeVj6fdx@tcBvxKCxn@RtiXsqsc7QnsJHidXHih4X6j7K1sDQkrHv3W2jLZvrIr6BR22aRYcSjJirB0dUq/eDaSlq077H2c6xuihuOGzPnqiBMlsPgIcmtvuV1F9gYG/vYvZu/51RV0bS4hIfZ09ynYPK8YzKzR3fCORHxuuAH1@R9q4YQhVFuYjFELnV8OXEK8fKbEuS8mauD9cUCRpwr/Yguk/poU7ULAoKhdauVhZUfMxgjDf36/Gam2eutGO3u8sNME9IOXjTV4@k3W@lKn1ma5ftsZZX01C0213HIZO4@esXq4WyBZx9DHPoWMqnvbw5Ha3VSNeYSRwFnzzFlZ/JghOMeLvaxCzmU9nAZRrHtynu3JmWFVwsVv11H5Liq9pQ2BYq1tB4h9g50J3WHgt3HUA3Vub8SuMb8VaCd6W83TNXdzbSQxj9vabkcXpftWTO2ySD7wgyYl3pKh/u/Et9dfTc8/xIw1lW5ufKdbBWh/ylmcO@O3joI0AQhOwtFFaGCbczu@zfTD@9ODl3RSxQlmS7zGGD/AFpthVE0ko6CbiF775u1HKRcb3LH6Kvk2i/RVsTr5UxvpmC4W0ik7xBvQiLlHPQ3ibrXlUdBTlp47W4sBXZe683m8FxqRYLioCEcuYRkuNHDdAJ5liW5GM3m/cpUi2agsrqwqrIm7e7JOW0NJJuGO1LT8NWTxWdCVW2F4MXxCCpqexoz65vIdPpdurNX9FY4ctpHI7shF784WQvIQbJFOf2TeYs7NQuNt6lrs45Lz4LWUGasVuvpXxSG8dqWaVeTn4rwLgit@wSb0tmoVhJbih51TVEHttpiRJJD3dHiGMboXnLiJMnKQLL47YDPpxCl@JWe6@@7vptTBjarHEZVxV3pLaE0l2v3yz6WuNLsNJkwRuv2uyXXWl9RWiW7avY9qdUxEyKWdrGGD8o2Up32grqRSCizOBy@R2@2Ykc6L3hVqXMlElG59rnbSX0p/Tf0LxSXL1CwQxQvzrUuwYJj1iyeHDcuh5WrXsdxx4HfYhwH@RtYk03VsTFiszMAqkyTuQsTqqeOJw@vvm5K7eMdG47aZhYbZtu7yhhKFgnx3OfOKAnfekgN3hzpzHztWhNNlmC44mx7DALsie4tmic5QLd2zcanhGDYB0oEkXKQExp09lEaj923iAMh9LyzdLP8zVuuDaKxW@t6PUlIKJXnJhDXk4o4lUSULkrG6rduDpuN1oITTJ3H4oYQgRptmkGAq@c1u0o8lXA/duwy1SgeYse8uZCw@KlNvl8nfTgTSwHtbfp@wo8vRHmIeS5slFaiLhqVmTRtsbs/MAV8EPJeKrRrKuOCG@@sWoWsOMzW@Vf0Z3WFUGDEPHU3Mz54@hhefWZ/ArNyFpH3iEub8pkAMcv@vWIkvmrJXkez0NIVREgZM6eFB@lQx7MLdKzMzpPZ5DmawGka8vV2mmfGOa6FUm1emHO@WEJks0d15lMT3a7aUFubJ4LYyUBMiyXYOfLaPR5FNMiznVjnE00Z3ENcUZ2tu1IqmjWV3vvTK6g/vfyl/GLG2dTUzVsdC2y@8Z5VQi/iHBFTsvZCvY4yo9d1VtsrxhMu@ebz0bXlPHNlo4UYTSWXcddQ4psXfOG5zw9S8fKgZYp@yQMro8kvjWscKi1Of/M2U70zRkHaezTyPNLLXjuJ2Be3FVwF3GjW0G7JU3k0Ki61zLDhp4ncJXFkORj5DiQa1POu0PigW96oZ/HjjsAQ4AK0Qo@HhE6m/qJ0Eho57lGkw2ZRCO@39MedyEbPoG2HzJNUOdJzhuYOMFAjiSs3p336Kzl13oa6HTMvPjnBynnXCIipTztDE4RW/d93jOiwCV/c84IpW8/d2t3v7UizpjQ/iMU4UbDl7J8tAQ88ew4@bbGiwZ2SZFQTMF1yVKpT9jEg3ARuT7r7Mvc6RjscSlD4CahUkb9ZnHdO6V25NOKaR18avXNzdWxU8uXoGAo943Iq5cqKADWiWLOMSJHgAeScEJ3IzOe5L6sHtf1FngpVA1loVYbHdyF1ASDJ9icuwFzfP2QfX/zUut2zTTebxXvxc1sJ918QvtI0XVV2zoPxM8wFnRgLqmHFw9NG0vTr2vnbcHgT0/1pa9hZtvx6K/lBhMXx1LKqpDrowjSsQVfPbttXR/F6TdHEVbVo7LHIEsREap4bGy/b7SKueiRK6xI8UXclnEmov7bBLQ8Y2VJy3e85Fo/gmaA5BrH@nw9F4RycVNyavtg7p92SZbvV3c6aNj@xct5DnMj79Kh@VKYtsO0JQoAttxWEUueonWGU/f9YpE@38zfkWK2eCkz0FZqJouU3Uer0u8wAkHrrWK5jFXoyCTo83yzzUUZ3BV6D5OiNEqlO2/Vpus2m0ut7B6QG8u59hG7HN5CaeRp4Tg8H/qttrC8aEhn5VC0Yb7igMV@DkUcy9C7X26WKpF7LHsZhE546Uxv3WcmC7QyB9OlvTAu98uc/f1ZXRDE4yp8XtuO@1VfiY92NOlS2c18p1yqOmVrWlke3Gf0OyK4btGBCi/H/Oz57qQJVwGierud/SeCFiTPZ7E5CA0P8Tnp1rpaLgJ3MI335q84fAj6tNsRGWT9TtrtdxHFWraufq/YvVvtXl1rsByakQDCw1mdGrc@x6/zqinu@2zaXwNGyXNmwUd1cbOaVYp9pwjc6AsEW0cKOQ9PTZAAvn4f5cNom8nYdSkKtlPO7ESNYG@eShGnV/NMngz6XkZLrwemQp02Zl6YzNE2lda4KdFKFa9W88ffx4uuW/d8KZoS8AlU0RMJnVapp6OWcua/3euv09dDVU2JdMeFOuOywEdllnkkzQBae7Byv0l9WcrFkTGkj/IEFjDP@iCC4@7Ng3F5FjvhrBaG1lFwD/buID/fPcJVVWnm3WMSSfpijcKANCiffy3tJlLWtxqtbWs6mM8qKulzTrsUSff6UFKsUoTUaYNnTU3PX6740NlcatdRNnvbEaD4iJ0SW4vRPfKdmYHv2fCkXzHRsX/iy9kTqbqNqPXM3ha@0hKw323rqvjNBC8stazISV95qxSWQdHP3/Hl2F@ioWXD8GhzHzjDBfBQqeq9wYsY5RVOfNEg60xClJu05618M82sVZdNP93Yo7VZJ87YV6vR6FpO/vSFbuMjzNdWtayWj0npcabadPRi/7rw3srjGIUxiKZqsyTXaNsdP06yB1HUaOGsbdLAujMtLWuxj2qb8yM5hFW26QKO0ijOr4/c2/@uGuX342tckqy0v2sZdzCvav7sU2LAYUgsFecZGHJunEsQacrIhiRXogeLLKqkyVhtmVPuwTClt/0WeN9PzMz8GwFmNG7Va/JEXrKRXh7IwsZ2MqhJnUEUlLnUTJa50gpl1a9apS8woX3OBvVCBTlt1pZXJwmXVN/Xa@@u1C85TzOef08AmVQG1zw5IJ4/5xSCarGwa8YEKVMlGKgcxf7gkz25iMATlKzhCZy0ldMs74DZBTm2W8MhJ85ad5QNSaG2ucPSsfSiu51680yjdtU12N1sjNkJlLsmr7VWqYnH/cXytqZaKdkff05ZUUd4Q4y5Zjnp@h2TErYfBCY3p1iFcjbMcjNubd/QBfdxFfnjaM5usJIiPTw7le1RNYNe7i1wk/WoltCh6YgOpVw13NwC1J0mGWhfN3U4RpUaapGa0lPtG69yQZThN5zs6tIUr0uJSYLeNVe8UruD4k62UVh4yx31r@eF3fxp6gzUVWoIVpHZ1etASsEFJbJIkGx1LDmEKVjy3QIZ3/XRsxje1Z@Aeh3xGRuKPoflxX3cqU7qMjmVVJkWeA6M0u@C5miWOggi5jWLBehc5WHM3/Ocq@bXDz6q/wmg@xX2lkQcj8TfZY8Zc/FpwnrDqf7AlkNxCPMPp3V@MPk8L4M9TazsU2ZXb@PHsdsXba75q4Jj4dteD6b1gVK75vkT@vKawyDth2ZIz@EkmJqpOQk5ya3LkpPWjfVZZF2gsZy8WSLN5bC2BZyWFsXeVZjfW1qa0HxYiqB7mGyxg8IJunFxQL1HxhE1tWl6RCV4ebxSCJaqCGvcLqJV@mI3nhklKDSmjZx8hoIUH3e0C923tDJJ9aDW7t6qoWALfvlwZOwuM3F@YV1tvQMzYZkgP3Vojm6qBIWuBDNPsalamctMdj2F6ZT6OUbsWVKnebdH@votBG3tT77Cyc5fI3wO5ZO/lsqGEx43@/zaOeIymILEXEN5WVxHV1eQsOzIbc13pnGTm0DcvfipVkskcaGrRtSLJC@f2FVa3Eq5cEMYA6vfbHqFiyJcZVPRzBA0HlqfPotost3dYRr@ie98pEH1KzlIDEzZLPjiuuvkGvq0rQOj2oXzhIolpYR1RjilyOWhxGzUdo/CNAY4C9U2Ope0qkWm3s6mCLQ29Y1prnCGLc2ry8GD8TAlhZoVWKIU9HbX89MpBErEj/IeSsb0dxgxSYPOCdVLr4RpWsIViHQsIR9eBCYnJW9yTbsf3@7bizztpo/p3QSeUxnYredqluIfVqfOENGhQhfQpt1dG3Zt8Us3q5kOn6K9k15SGr6fWYH/ne1VnFYxleUaOHWog9HA@zVHpOkeMTmpiNEb8bRlkWmfF/pQHoSbXQZwUxubrKXXIMCfqjrU6Wmi6/iOvXPz3kPKkHA9IHizt6u5jW68Dj/fwlg6wgmDV82pyCZX4SdWfgnB9oQ5ONiWbvxJUfKqTqjjq8kMN08WZ1hvD2RKY4rgP46TUbxGUvqj1CRu91J1ib2w1rTBk4JxM81j0lRDrpQIAPC/AQ)

A pretty uninteresting brute-force solution. Only uses alphanumeric characters and `|`, so a) flavor doesn't really matter b) I expect this to be easily beaten by a smarter brute-force solution at least.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), score 122.39

```python
count = 0
total = 0
while True:
    y = [input() for _ in range(50)]
    input()
    n = [input() for _ in range(50)]
    input()
    input()
    s = set()
    for x in y:
        i = 1
        while any(a[:i] == x[:i] for a in n):
            i += 1
        s.add(x[:i])
    regex = "^(" + "|".join(s) + ").*"
    count += 1
    total += len(regex)
    print(regex)
    print(total / count)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZjHjjU5gp3Xzaf4UasqDdAaQdBmgF6E994yBiOBYcmwjGA4BubdW8wqQQuttMnkTZqkPec7l/ITb@t//@c/m@1az1//@PWv4NxONP9ZejCZu1/pcXX/Bv7GxZ/@naz0On//41e/Hb/@1y@y/jrQOnS//49//eM/wN/@TyX42/r/3/T/Fpjow7o/iz893p8eXPzbvxFR8d/E778mg1b@O/r3fyP/8esf//j1/ln4aY5@mq9//LQXHf7lrx7s76htf/@zkRj16IbuFWP99j9//@3Xv/z67T9/@/u4kfV39sfPpz/@/l9@A3/7axP@6v7XNojy3K2//9lZDEIPsp7/z6e/Gv7XX392/uOf/5T78qA4VZstTOVsWhVthp/GzGqPWT@k00gRbObSGCTfSkx9a3fA5856Sb6EI4qM893VQ/M4rNwUpbHapXkiedCo0xxVd6on3SiXYEkOZ2RrPameu05YKy/pHkzFXestO6a3Ozu5Jsl7fu2iGFnpajFo15Jsc3bz1HAk1PoWdGG370ZalWR4LnvxdKyuQZj1NTyXwiUYkDf0zkjVbL1ijQLN2efVmvU7Zgu2p/3J88uKjSR4zHzd9La8E6BMw@DOyxZ4Jffv2jXWeS8qxzlgkdlB7scrD7EWltaMZG/6UqqDbMl51u5qqg7J06ayem1mpbXK2o@GpqLEaz7iVMUobdVSJ3L2bWLH@Ly6n5RY07fzfsC287DRidtG19W9jxva7Wr87tujPXbb@@UE2uMKNM3ZKbX1djkgJFWA/doj4Xk1yanMc2qcaJwqde6/uZOyD@gjWpS5vNwseS72veHXWUqiH8/mfAMTq/JsaCuNvOOLKwTVWQEOR3ZdM2VXV8qSXiItO85ETUsnKJEFlSFPjlmnrBM3AzexJxkTWGgWS7pEUcOabDGfMmL71CLzRosh14s6ZHtbfIxI68jGemn8HHykjKWkfkeIXBVqFZKQuEJVGyw5qwc3uBC@d5SNm0m1B6s8fYC67kNEPjLrUJt22lnHMHnx5KnZNV1LOp3EMuxQzzOYOrKjP7ULLhiWCt@M4zKm8Q2NMag2qAXTHrEFrWbb6t/xLZAoTpt@Y/O6Hmg9bGSPPyRxyVDdpSUdYDDJ@sH8bOtQWZdSpjfKqKItSJ4kpAmYGNtLPzr3LPKsm9KA@Y2yFKalPmrBjXan5zmtyLKXwzztIAs7AMmXF/kS@H12FlBXiq5m4UjlNQ3nxjKjKjpuzSJJaG8nO9/qvECTn@d8KaR9VJ172XtpjsyNc5D7MYOowIcyS@u1d36cFDx@07EFXhZFzuKduMxb7ySyWnxBgNz4OXM7TmhnKKja0VmoaRJtC@79ASRCDFhHtVc/paCv62TV5CDxmO69YdB2JF@1ASWj05bP0JBlsG4Qr9lQmElrDh561jynacSxgsfGdHG9GW/uuOZW9knMkyD2DZy0AGaRNbKPDrV6TstiBXElIz8sq4nF9Bj2dqYevHNHKrxM75lhFEAb2ku9@dLh1X70oVjNXiW9Hadon4xHnMWe5jPMZYautAizGAUg@kiuTrBulY8W3UPTzS0KHNdGaRxutdf80eVleXnmzNd15e5egtZuiB4uG9zl8y20hH/QPXCbWtEcTmNYJ16Qrg3v9@EKaZaWUgMcpWFT/IbyvbEtX0tbCdPC4yl3oIlb9@sMem45N6otbJzz1OwHKPuW0Asq9bPKmFpGhWTcvkfZBtlnp2@i6Wcm7fE8adA0u8WoT9A0sTiPr@893VypXclWmPpOFjp8pDeTskWT9knjMcmsix53kFOwKa9tO2WcKLPc5INnVDDBB7Tl08SwaTVLcrNuSAvZcY/L12wnBxIXRf5ZhqzX1ncXiqKIakWFcZwTP4QhSbTR2V/HeNLOWPPOB3GSp28dWLO@nYmXaXHqfNUs5ucpw/aa7ZY8lnJxy3HDQx1eSUvAEbZT/5V2KrQTu7S4stfh1@W4RRQ/MbGsNhQS8VlITm00verSgNqfdmeFQxqYS9qg5Xy5OO5gqwpV3qfI2zg5jKSsZV9I1eRc8gqI0U6y1celd7vnwvuFLFzfei@NQ8vG53W6En/HZeZBW5G9CLYNnBi5fIlXZQ5JVqhPrmgmKa/wHpbOI3ozdyorg0hzuNcUXqpMDzCcSB@0SnXHVklWLgmNiouVd6U6WbvjouDQ53aY2M1ptz6W3kwAjk0VlgEsisNPos9eSR3d3DnfudBcxal9h0@6pBSWKudI7zy3BWubv4OyDuqejVhOyaWKV2/fSew01Srv0nA0wQO1J2JyNeZm8qWg92GhD5PDKmRsh6R09DTu52z74FxMHJMvNQJiBv687ZE0arQmQFrXtGmKtQo12lamuetLDUPnWiR1MfC42zR2kqxn3sLv3bh8eQetdh6f0gbSGJbk5Q@zeuV6zWFOQqWCs84nxMw24p0wnVgycdKDUL7IuKTYQSqfk0S2ntgYJ1YVqYnrNraHcVXyAe2Bem981Go6AKhtfpv4TP9qHYq1m9eIj/jaoW9aXbfqcZgj85zcQmaTeXzquAOWBm4jZi69nxNh8pRj8wzOpywPOa7NkNU153Rg0Z5PjGy1xncwRn0c9dNg@tSzK8Ir5mrGIPuGFI6B@KF8Ye9dMRkSz3k6e5UfIJ@GRg8HvcZW32muNqumtttl7N76ZW3EyhFPzbw5JvGHUoHd8wFCq60bKitauQudfKPLlJFsGfW8nMdrxTgLLroiP7J4GHlMaBvIa1KMh/1UbkkqWzvYLudZG1bLDdsLxl6UzW8ZKEomOY/t97rbgLFYNCqdkktXucsunMK48Ss/kA9D60mMIjIgSRlCrs/nRtKosgBoYBxFhdCgwc2nKTTHoFcLpeuFL5/pHNEiqhezLGEm3gst@r4goEpCaWjX9R2HQCl3imxGHcmVMye@7NReH/pa9Bb1J0FVuWxsBZp5uIb6yEnmbU9q36MvTPurO8OK@sYZ9BjqsLIH2o1nYZA2MwdQmPNkWJ5x5I/edissjyE@uyRszniZu7e7DLxG4VheRnyPsWCYC9TN9BZXc/X2FuVWoMFM/1RNdaS9vk7PGfBX@EYYTJZ8zo0yJdoEskRdyy3IZS@gZ00zTWh5T/rqzI7rHktH3aBR6lo/pdmEUk1jjjj@id8OC6x0n1GwnIVOZBaHvA1lpDAyj8lSficMnzrbizku7hE8I4@6V/vG4m1DZzEN6D9XiBkvYDbk0pHP0o3dXh402kfCpKoYnNqXvlYojdfUBfKpy3RtR261nmHJKpk4X5pmCotDvQRZtHeTbcBl8lIhWqZeWI4e5HEqhLedGvqN5bwo77E5NJWt6oui2JZky@qB88kFs@DO0PSNoTFfoae5l79rKy7PdRymoiX9GKnqido4lya/ASlEKHNLvfvcuFNQoJd6FeZ4HDY94v3zylkS1ULrJbKaNf4@vQHBrYUESWE/@MnlfbCxOH@v8gsyryCvNnwS9hs7rm90ZlebeXsM@qpT1cbW/UYITIXLSVsU/6VIwzb9kLEuiV1qUb4eb7@5bzGvIVA7x1XeokxN8WBlOhDP4qlCpDuEs83X/SgLz3Efj6uSSQMoggOA29fIaQPtT3IF6sY4ezc8dilcnE0uHe9kDvrKvH8jeXXDdrYc0CzJ43r9XMhZicfjmiauui@@NNcnCwwLlmfugzSibPmXHbeaqADL16e@yZLTeUmq8ajU/tBsieZdK6lhoORvWbOgh3FNBrINsrICvNvI3bQ8SjootbViOUKvdwbnYTadtOvkSDsC81XzQmImzpQ5A99suP5IqSV3Zmun2bEniTb0lpG4Zypd5pIf9lvbuyDWTbPqoJWBwb9E33Hgv4JyAntPu0EdhzAIPm75kR6P6uggvtDG6JHQsiGywLLPi5fkqlcZTVVkkVolbwiZgi2ETd12/eHMs1vaKdM2VcusAoK6jlnxLGIFiToq@3rN0@G/ql1dHfPmHzfIH9/oZnuQvWKilh4DVh2DDOllIA9/3au/0d4mSQHDcx/CD6@KC60ZT76zm6VzDUO/AG5A5XJjuS59uw8Y/bbkFbbi6h/qZL03AjjHq5dMuv8tlkHHOgKPNodakK3X51p8tqXU23V@IVt3whqrzY5WFVdBWnm7wKRqPk4PLJ79@jTYadQcbh/ZsAg97At@H7Utkps6Owp/czrvri9Zm3FAHMACiTTNPH2BuhGFW3SUDf4iS5rdvgyf@D6y93RLeRSYhWua9g5woMgppXWb8qOdjBh44sNCXC@ZnXDCqSwXk34TuMTTmlReKHwYuPEQPt9PpKfsIZenfrVFRtIa5zh1uqnX4dCMq@@yGY7OcEs4AG8gNRI5wjV0BH71Ry1gTu/pVM5Sazuz6nVWfU9KYuz5qpJgFtHClnhyPlfVekdhQt06cQW98jrf@1ifI2sWS9UiwSSLQ4fsfJmugk@zMqYmzC3jYF/yXKpPcx0VNeztSEGOO/Q1y7nnojPyXjMOXyRyQriY6cqt2vHcxexMRfSunOcpnC0UuXG1Rv1iTeUdqT5laqRpwBog755WS/XPa0s/SQQc@VHK6o4vq9Q3RRyd7XHLS9uUAru3HQLLbraNe4uRYTP2pb4PBnYnQZhJVqXRWCvaa27yzWehmEOt9/4FZqE9AwsFItMzkStoXVmLzt0caLlOrDW2VNenStlSuy0c/8NOBjKNXGunxqy0X8yz@hiLlB7p0S/UTsmK@u3Kjvio5l2s31W3qwSOqMdFXnaQyLe/sLw1qyK5sBrdF3KRf@xp0w8BKzrJWaxUmyNgBEdGDr/U8zvQa0EdDQy7ZthDOkhBKnF1KN0vqs07hkMfzz1PgBrMVC/rtZ7iORUAgtTFlKvsC5/Xtb0mtN2LXJnX0hBtm3IQXIGGnL66DWgtXMG4VbcezJxN2bzrwJiuY296pIQ8mVSjf9I3l3obWN/nXS1qV85CyT3fd35MjjJbxt58F8kK/ardsLF2wiEvVEvNB1yTEe/1vsSwb7Oq5LHuSTJQ05eVF9b72FJdiZtvE9dj0bMufgeALabXm3tFxscEEGTCIJYky06RG32DdgVVw3pXQ3L0IyvYpdsbIEN0qUaYh0dH2ZVUwv/CcYrqbdrJ@ERO8yg4n6AubzMZtcJzc1A9GYOSb0W7XgVfVhUVjbxjHLRTrEkb5kxQmJADtRmuXVnCRmEAInxvJ5RnJMVmnX6sgVzTssO5ZRTE5HWW10ALmSmX/VLSTOiAEEnTnadooHtdtgcRw0bWotUTvuduadx0N7MIFiKF6VRJc4nk4LKukooI9pDkSjwlRBV212QYCotoZx/a3xen5Xjqy6p0zV4ZuwwACKc7bMs9m72H1VWVC1i0TFl35EVN4mayj@mOtlaMnMcxuwur04GGd@roShKY2@FnpYAVLzOv2w5iu2ZfHMMmsZN7hIw7XRVLm6Brbm7OGxoXmpq1UUI1@EQIztbiJg4WWUgzZDnEmN7t5ASf07p5Bc59HmzFrMxN8SJ4dnQrhqeZG5qksW3EjSlA0zws/T5uv1rgN3agsZ/kbbF7KrHO0J7CR4nVx4oeF@o@ytbA0JJxGNxtoy2b6yK@gUdtmkWHEowdVw@OqFbvB9NS1KbD0GU779RFcUOyPXuiBspsPQAemjjuV1J/wMDe3sUc3OE7o76MpMXFfpc9yXUSlXczKjd3fCOQHxmvA358RTq4YgpVFOUiFkPkVuTLsVeOldmWOOXNXB@uKRI04F7tQXSf0kOdqFkUFAqtXa0sqPiYwbjb3G/o1tw8c6Ud@91dbtDxBJfEm756xO1@K1XpM1u7bI@1vJpI0W53HYdM4ubPN1YLZQs4hxjm0LGUT3t5czpaq@G@MZM4Cj55iis/kwUnGPF2tYlZzKeygcs0jm9T3Lk3LSu4WKz6606S4qvaUNgWKtbQeEnsHOhOa4@Fuw6gGytzfqXxjXgrwbtS3v6Zqzsb6SGM/l5T/DiDr1oy522SwXcEGbaudJUPd/5RXx099zw/EjnLyvxcuQ7W6pC/NHPYdwcPfQQIgpC9hcLKMOF2ZpfDm@mnFyfnrogNypJslzlskE@QZltBJK24l4Bb@O7rRi0XGde7fBJ9vUSHLdqaeK2M8c2UDt4mMvEb1IuwSDkH7W2y/lXVUZCTNl6LC1uRvfd6sxkcl2qxoAhIKGcexnn3qAE6wRzLknzsZvM@RapFU1BZfVgVefP2l6SclobTrUP7MtCw1VNFZ0KV7cXgBTZwaio72rPrW/B0ur1681d0VvhyGocjO6EXf12yl7ADyRTn9o3nLOzVPjbepa7OOS8@C1lBmrFbr6V8UhvHalmlXk5@K8C4IrfsE29LZqFYSW4oedU3WB7baYkSSQ93R4hjG6F5y7CTJykCy@O2pDucQpfiVnuvoe6HbUwY2qxxGVe163FtCaW7Xr9Z9LXuLsFKkwXvbtVmv@xL6ytCs2xfxbY/pcJmUszSNsbdg5KtdKetoF4EIsoMLpff4Zu9yIHeG25VykwZZ3Sufd5WQn9K/w3NK@2qVyiYAepXh3rfIOERSxYTx61rsmr96zj2SHQSdUOQt4k13Z0iHlZkZhZIlXHCZ3FS9ezC6eObn7tyy3DvtpPWYatt0@0dpQ4K1sm7eUgcMOChdJAbvLnTmPlatCabLMHx2Fh2mAXZE1xbNM5yge7tGw3PiEGwEopElUKwKW06m3Dtx84bhCEpLd8s/Txf44Zro9j81opeXwIiesWJSfJyQhGvkoDKfdlQ7e6q43ajBdMkc3dSxBAiSLNNMxB45bRuR5GvAu7fhl2mAs1b9OA3FxoWL7XJ5@ukB29iOai9Td9X4OmNMA8hz5WN0kLEVbPCi7Y1Zu8HroAfisdTjWZddUR4841Vs4Adn9kq/0R3WlcYESHiqbmZ88fRw/LqM/kVmpG1jrxHXN6UyQCOXwzrESXzV0vyPJ6HkKoiQMicPSk@Sgc/HbfwwM7oPB0izdcCcN@Wq7XTITHMdSuSavXCnPPDEiSbO64zmZ7s9tOC3Ng8F8ZKDGRYLsHOl9EY8iimRZzrxjibaM7iGnYZ3tm2I6mi2VDtgzO5gvrfy1/GL26cTU3VsNG1yB4a51Uh/CLMFTktZyvY4yg/dlVvO3vtwLR7vvlsdE0Z32zpSFGHxrLvuWtIka1rHnnO07P0TjnQMmWf1IHrw4lvkRWSWpvzz5ztRN@ckUjjkEaeX2rBcz8B8@K@gruIG/0K2i1pIodG1b2WWWfoeQJXWUxJPkbeBXJtynl/SDzwTS/089hxCTAEqGCt4OMRobOpnwiNmPaeazQZySQa8f2e9rgPGfkE2n7INEGdJzlvYOIEBB9JWL07H9BZy6/1NNDpmXnxzw9SzrmERUp52hmcIrbu@7xnWIFL/uacYUrfYe7X/n5rRdwxof1HKMKN1l3K8tES8MSz4@TbGi8i7JIioZiC65KlUp@wiYlwEbk@6@zL3Okg9riUIXCTUCmjYbO47p1SO/Jp7WgdfGr1zc3Vs1PLl6BgKPeNyKuXKihAp2PFnGOEj6AjOOGY7kZmPMl9WUNX11vgpVA1lIVabXRwF1ITEE@wOXcD5vj6Ifv@5qXW7ZppvN9qtxc3s5108zEdIkXXVW3rPRA/ZCwoYS6uyduRpo2l6efZeVtA/OmpvvQ1zGw7Hv213GDi4lpKWRVyfRRBOrbgq2e3reujuP3mKMKqelT2GGQpwkIVj43t941WsRY9coUVKb6I23KXiaj/NgEtz1hZ0vIdL7nWj6AhEF/jWJ@v54JQLm6KT20n5v5pl2T5fnWnROvsH17Oc5gbeZ@S5kth2pJpSxQAbLmtIpY8ReuQU/f9YpE@38zfkXZs8VJmoK3UTBYpu49WZdhhBILWW8V2GavQkUnQ5/lmm4syuCv0JpOiNEqlO2/Vpus2m0ut7B6QG8u59rFzObyF0sjTwrvwfOi32sLyIpLOyqFoZL7igMV@DkUcy9C7X26WKpF7LHsZhE546Uxv3WfGC7Qyp6NLe3VduV/m7O/P6oIgHlfh89p23K/6Sny0o0mXyn7mO@VS1Stb08oycZ/R77HgukUHKrwc87Pnu5emrgoQ1dvtHD4RtCB@PovNQWh4iM9Jv9bVcmG4g2m8N3/twgejT7sdkUHW76T9fhdRrGXr6g@KPbjV7tW1BkvSjBhgHs7q1Lj1OX69V03xMGTT/howSp4zCz6qi5fVrFLsO0XgRl8g2DpS8Hl4aoIE8A37KB9G20zGrktRsJ1yZidqBAfzVIo4vZpn8mQwDDJaBj0wFeq0MfPCZI62qbTGTYlWqni1mj/@Pl503frnS9GUgE@gip5I6LRKPR21lDP/7V9/nb4BqmqKpTsu1Lkri@6ozDKPpBlAaw9W7jepL0u5uDKG9FGewALm2RBEcNy9mRiXZ7ETzmphaD0FN7F3B/n57mGuqkoz7x6TcDIUaxQGuEH5/LO1m0hZ32q0tq3pYD6rqKTPOe1SJN3rQ3GxShFSpw2eNTU9f7niQ2dzqV1H2extj4HiI3ZKbC1G98h3Zga@Z8OTfsVEx@GJL2dPpOo2otYzB1v4SovBfretq3ZvJnhhqWVFTobKW6WwDIph/o4v7/wlIi0j5NHmIXDIBTpSqeq9wQsb5RVOfNEg602MlRu35618M82sVZdNP93Yo7VZL@7YV6vR6FpO/gyFbndHmK@talktH5PS40y16ejF/nV1eyuPYxTGIJqqzZJco2337nGSPYiiRgtnbZMI68@0tKzFPqptzo/kEFbZpgs4SqM4vyFyb/@7apTfj69xSbLS4a7lrod5VfNnnxIDEpJYapdngOTcOJcg0pSRkSRXoqcTWVRJk7HaMqfcAzKlt/0W3b6fHTPzbwQdo3GrXpMn8pKN9PJAVmdsJ4Oa1BtYQZlLzWSZK61QVv2qVfoCE9rnbFAvVJDTZm159ZJwSfV9vfbuS/2S8zTj@fcEkEllcM2TA@L5c04hqBYL@2ZMkDJVgoHKUZxPd7InFxF4gpJFnsBJWznN8h6YfZB3dms4@Oyy1h1lQ1Kobe6wdCy96G@n3jzTqF11DXY3G2N2AuWu8WutVWp24/528ramWinZH39OWVFHeMOu45rlpOt3TErYfhCY3JxiFcoZmeVm3NqhoUs3xFXkj6M5u8GKi/Tw7FS2R9UMBnmwwI3Xo1pCh6YjOpRy1brmFqDuNAmhQ93U4RhVaqhFakpPdWi8ygVR1r3hZFeXpnh9ik0cDK65diu1eyjeZBuFhbfc0fB6XtjPn6bOQF2lBncqMvt6JbgUXFAiCwfJVseSg5nSSb5bIOO7PnoW5F39CajXEZ@xoehzWF7c73rVSV0mp5Iq06KbA6P0@6A5mqUOgoh5zWIBOld5GPP3POeq@fnCR/U/AXQ/YW9JxPVI/F32mDEXnyasN5zqD2w5FJcw/7q0zg8mn@dlsKeJlX3K7Opt/Dh2h6LNNX9Vulj4tjeAaX2g1K55/oS@vOYwSAfSkPQkJ@6omZqTkJPcuiw5ad1Yn0XWBRrL8Zsl0lyStS3gtLQo9q7C/N7S0oTmw1IE3cNkix0UTtCPiwPqPTKOqKlN08Mq7pbHK4VgqYqwxu3CWqUvduOZUYJCY9rwyWcoSPFxR7vQfUsrk1QPau0erBoKtuCXD0fG7jIT9xfW1TY4MBOWCfJTh@bopkpQ6Eow87QzVStzmcmupzCdUj/HiD1L6jTv9kjfsIWgrf3JVzje@WuEz6F88tdS2XDC42afXztHXAZTkJhrKC@L6@jqChKWHbmt@c40bnITiLcXP9VqiSQudNWIBpHk5bNzlbZrpVy4IYyBNWw2vcJFEa6yqWhmCBoPrU@fRTTZ7v4wDf/s7nykQfWTHCQGpmwWfHHddXKRIW3rwKh24TyhYkkpZr0RTilyeSgxG7X9ozCNAc5CtY3OJa1qkam3sykCrU19Y5qrLusszatL4sGYTEmhZkUnUQoGux/46RQCJeJHeQ8lY/pLxg6nQe@E6qVXwjQt4QpYOpaQkxeByUnxm1zT7se3@w4iT7vpY3o3hudUBnbruZql@IfVqzNElFToAtq0u2vDri1@6WY10@FTtPfSi0vD9zMr8L@zvYrTKqayXAOnDnUwGt1@zRFu@kcsTipi9EY8bVlk2ueFPpQH4WaXAdzUxsZr6TUI8KeqDnV6mug6vmPv3XzwkEISrge42@ztam6jH6/Dz7cwlo5w6sCr5lRkk6vwEyu/hGB7whyczpbu7pOi5FWdUO@uJjPcPFkcst4eyJTGFMF/HCejeI2k9EepSdz@peoSe2GtacSTgnEzzWPSVEOulAgA8L8B) Explanation: Simply takes the set of minimal prefixes of the strings in the first list that aren't prefixes of any strings of the second list and uses that to build a regex.

Comment: This is a pretty nice answer, but I think it misses a `^` at the start of the regexes generated: from the question "does not match **any** of the strings in the second list" [see in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jaiPRw/1). With just a `^` it works: [see in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mCbaBB/1) and it's just 1 byte more

Comment: @Kaddath My regex was designed to work with Python's `re.fullmatch`. If I can use `re.match` then I can save two bytes. If I'm forced to use `re.search` then that will as you say cost me a byte. I'll ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: yes maybe that's one of the reason the post is closed, it could be clearer.. however I don't understand why the other answer got upvoted and not this one, as the other doesn't match the full string but just part of it..

Comment: @Kaddath Perhaps people didn't read the spec clearly enough - I only noticed my mistake too after reading your comment. Anyway, I've fixed my answer for a slight score increase by just surrounding my partial match with `^.*(...).*$` - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino You don't need the trailing `$` though, since the `.*` is greedy.